# Two forms in Django- how to make form submittable without all fields full?

Tags: html, django

I have two forms in one view. I want to be able to submit one form WITHOUT filling out the other. I have figured out how to process the forms seperately by having a different action for each form, but I am using django ModelForms and all fields need to be filled before either form can be submitted.

I have tried making the fields optional but it does not work for my use, I need all the fields in each form to be filled out in order to be submitted.

Here is my HTML:

```
      <form method="post" action="successfulpost" class="form-inline">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{applicantform}}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="View full posting"></input> 
      </div>
```

And my form code:

```
class ApplicantForm(forms.ModelForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First name'}), label='')
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last name'}), label='')
    referrer = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Referral.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Applicant
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'referrer')
```

Is this possible to do- maybe not possible with ModelForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering both forms in separate `<form> </form>` maybe solve your problem
like

```
<form method="post" action="successfulpost" class="form-inline">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{first_form}}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="View full posting"></input> 
      </div>
```

and

```
<form method="post" action="successfulpost" class="form-inline">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{second_form}}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="View full posting"></input> 
      </div>
```